# Im trying to make a my current weather temperature displayed in notification badge's

Tags: swift, xcode, weather-api

Im trying to make a weather app so far I have everything done however I was working on notifications and I want my current temperature to show on the home screen displayed as a badge.

So far I have tried to display the `tempLabel` however I get the error that

> Cannot assign value of type 'UILabel?' to type 'NSNumber?'.

```
self.locationLabel.text = jsonResponse["name"].stringValue
self.conditionImageView.image = UIImage(named: iconName)
self.conditionLabel.text = jsonWeather["main"].stringValue
self.temperatureLabel.text = "\(Int(round(jsonTemp["temp"].doubleValue)))"

let date = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
self.dayLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

let suffix = iconName.suffix(1)
if (suffix == "n") {
    self.setGreyGradientBackground()
} else {
    self.setBlueGradientBackground()
}

// Step 1: Ask for permission
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
}

// Step 2: Create the notification content
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Daily Reminder"
content.body = "Dont forget to check today's weather"
content.badge = (temperatureLabel)
```

I would like for my `temperatureLabel` to be shown in a badge format.

```
self.temperatureLabel.text = "\(Int(round(jsonTemp["temp"].doubleValue)))"

let badgeCount: Int = temperatureLabel
```

How ever I'm getting this error,

> Cannot convert value of type 'UILabel?' to specified type 'Int'

Comment: Maybe read the documentation for UNMutableNotificationContent and specially what badge is?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up types. The error says

- `temperatureLabel` is `UILabel`
- The `badge` property is `NSNumber` (can be `Int` or `Double`)

The solution is to get first the `Int` value of the temperature, then assign the `Int` to the badge and convert it to `String` for the label.

```
let badgeCount = Int(round(jsonTemp["temp"].doubleValue)
content.badge = badgeCount
self.temperatureLabel.text = "\(badgeCount)"
```

Comment: However I am troubled with "jsonTemp" being declared after the "notification/content.badge = badgeCount" and if I just put the notification code lower I am troubled with my code having a lot of issues.

Comment: Also if I put "let badgeCount = Int(round(jsonTemp["temp"].doubleValue))" I get the following error "Use of unresolved identifier 'jsonTemp'"

Comment: Of course the code must be in the scope where `jsonTemp` is available. From the given code is unclear where it's declared. If you are talking about `OpenWeatherMap` it could just be `jsonWeather["main"]["temp"].doubleValue`